# Starting a game

Tags: java, android, 2d

I know this might not be the right place for this thread but i dont' really know where else to post this:
I'm hoping this thread to be a series of Q&A's as i progress with my project, so let's start.

I'm using android studio and right now i have the core layout for the game aswell as a working registry,now,I'm pretty much cluesless as to how to start the actual game. i know how to create basic pictures and animations and basic java, i've also spent several hours looking into starting a game and creating test projects but i still feel overwhelmed. my goal is to create an RPG game but for now i'll just use some stick figures and one "class" for the game. tips on how and where to start the actual game development would be much appreciated. keep in mind though that unless there's no choice i'd like it to be using android studio

Comment: _..i dont' really know where else to post this..._ Maybe on [android.stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What about you start here https://www.androidauthority.com/the-beginners-guide-to-android-game-development-692253/

Comment: As much as I'd like to help you OP, your question is off topic. There are a number of good books you can pick up on game development.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Unity 3D Game development Engine](https://unity3d.com/) for the development. It is easy to use and lot of tutorials available in youtube. I personally use Unity3d for android game developments and Android studio for non-game app developments.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are new to development and you are trying to build a game from 0 , i will say stop , read how games are build , what implies to create a game and all the things you need to learn.

The games that you see now days have on the background at several people working on it.

I don't have idea of what kind of game you want to create , but i will tell you to start with [Unity](https://unity3d.com/es/learn) , there are a lot of documents from where you can learn.

I hope not to disappoint you , but building a video game is way more complex and implies way more work of what people think.

So before even be able to build something simple , you have several hours of learning in front of you.

Good luck

Comment: the issue is that this game is supposed to be my school project which has to be made with android studio. i will start looking up guides and such as to how to start a game. but my point is i have several months to work on this and i'm willing to put in as much effort and time as necessary